# Unable to locate element

Tags: angular2, typescript, cucumber, protractor

Пишу вот такой код

```
browser.driver.wait(function () {
    return browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('.//span[contains(text(), \'ФИО\')]')).
    then(function (elem) {
        browser.sleep(5000);
        return true;
    });
}, 1000000);
```

После сборки, компилятор выдает ошибку:

```
NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//span[contains(text(), 'ФИО')]"}
```

Посдкажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в самом `xpath`. Попробуйте использовать
`by.xpath('//span[contains(text(), 'ФИО')]')`

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, лучше всегда пользоваться CSS-селекторами. Они понятнее и проще. И переходить к XPATH только при надобности.

```
by.cssContainingText('span', 'ФИО')
```

Comment: Вроде CSS-селекторы еще и быстрее. Было бы интересно увидеть конкретные цифры